# I need to click a blank space to remove the tool-tip as it is blocking the checkbox

Tags: python, selenium

I am writing a Selenium script to automate the deleting of all users. However, after clicking on the 'Delete' checkbox, the tool tip will appear and block the next checkbox which prevents my loop from carrying on. How can I click on an empty space or work around this issue?

This is the tool tip that is currently blocking me:

```
<td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original- 
title="on"><span class="input-group-btn justify-content-center">
<input type="checkbox" name="delete0"></span></td>
```

This is currently my loop that I am using to check all the checkboxes:

```
for item in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[starts-with(@name, 'delete')]"):
item.click()
```

I should expect to check all the checkbox but this is the error message:

```
Element <input type="checkbox" name="delete1"> is not clickable at point (1402, 436). Other element would receive the click: <div class="tooltip-inner">...</div>
```

Comment: Find a black space in the page and click on it after each checkbox click.

Comment: I have tried the following code but does not work
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//html").click()

Comment: Try a "real" element, a span of whitespace or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using javascript to click the element instead of the browser:

```
for item in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[starts-with(@name, 'delete')]"):
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", item);
```

Comment: thank you! I've successfully checked all the checkbox

Answer (score 0):

You can try moving away from element showing the tooltip using [ActionChains](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains).

Consider adding the following line after item.click() as part of your loop:

```
ActionChains(driver).move_by_offset(-1000, -1000).perform()
```

Comment: I've tried the following: 
`webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_by_offset(-1000, -1000).perform()`
however, the tool tip is still there and blocking my checkbox